# My iPhone 13 loses the internet when connected to my Macbook

Tags: iphone, internet

My new iPhone 13 loses Internet immediately when I plug in the cable to connect it to my MacBook.

I tried using a USB A to Apple lightning cable through a via USB hub. I tried USB C to Apple lightning cable plugged directly into my MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2020, Four Thunderbolt 3 ports). I also tried to connect to the USB port on my monitor which is connected to my MacBook via USB C. In all cases the iPhone is charging but doesn't have an internet connection.

What could be the problem?

Comment: What does "when I plug in the cable to connect it to my MacBook" mean? What model MacBook? What cable? What ports?

Comment: I tried USB A to apple lightning cable that connected via hub. I tried USB C to apple lightning cable directly to MacBook (2020). I also tried to connect to my Monitor that connected to my MacBook via USB C. In all cases iPhone is charging but doesn't have internet connection.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of your network settings on the iPhone (with sensitive information removed)?

Comment: @Questionmark What network settings do you mean? I have a page with wi-fi settings (almost nothing there actually) and mobile data. Internet is missing in both ways (Wifi and mobile).

Comment: I have an impression that it might be because of my MacBook. iPhone doesn't lose internet with other computers (other iMacs), only when connected to my MacBook.

Answer (score 0):

On MacBook Pro:

1. Open System Preferences
2. Open Sharing
3. Deselect Internet Sharing or put checkbox next to iPhone on the right labeled "To Computer Using"